# Laravel 5.2 - Share data with all views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have a header-user menu logged, each user registered have a balance import, i would like show this balance in my header section user logged, i'm tryng to use VIEW SHARE, like this but it doesn't work well:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        //its just a dummy data object.
        $balance = UserBalance::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

        // Sharing -  the error interested this section: 
        view()->share('balance', $balance->balance);
    }

}
```

MY ERROR

> ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 23: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

```
line 23 : view()->share('balance', $balance->balance);
```

MENU USER SECTION (inside my layout for all views):

```
@if (Auth::guest())
          <li><a href="{{ url('login')}}">Accedi</a></li>
          <li class="item-custom"><a href="{{url('register')}}">Registrati</a></li>
           @else
           <li class="hello-user">
           Ciao {{Auth::user()->name}}
           </li>
           <li> Your Balance: {{$balance}}</li>
@endif
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because AppServiceProvider boot method work first and  Auth::id())->first() return null, after that you try to get balance from null.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the *best* answer, but have you considered storing the results in the Session?

The session can be checked and read by any view.

```
if ($request->session()->has('balance')) {
     $request->session()->get('balance', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the user is logged in or not. If user not authenticate than `Auth::user()->id` can't be exists and you also need to check `$balance`. If the query return null than the error will be show.

> ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 23: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

Try this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
           //its just a dummy data object.
           $balance = UserBalance::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

            // Sharing -  the error interested this section: 
            view()->share('balance', (count($balance) > 0) ? $balance->balance : 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i'm logged yes! but dd(Auth::user()->id) return "null" i don't know why.

Comment: check the `dd(Auth::user())`

Answer (score 0):

Your Auth::id() return null or it does not retrieve session id. Because Laravel session is handled using session middleware and all middleware is executed before AppserviceProvider. As a result it does not retrieve session id.You can use this code. Because view()->composer clouser will be executed when the view is composed. Then you can use session id

```
        public function boot()
        {
            $this->getBalance();
        }

        public function getBalance()
        {
            view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
                    $balance = UserBalance::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
                    View()->share('balance', $balance->balance);
            });

        }
```